# How to address warning that tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated?

Tags: tensorflow

When attempting to import TensorFlow in a Jupyter Notebook, I encounter the following warning message

```
import tensorflow as tf

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\bhara\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name 
tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use 
tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.
```

I tried to import TensorFlow in my Jupyter Notebook using the standard import tensorflow as tf statement. I was expecting the import to work without any warnings or issues. However, I received a warning stating that tf.Session is deprecated and that I should use tf.compat.v1.Session instead. How to address this warning?

Comment: You can try to update your tensorflow package version: `pip install -U tensorflow`.

Comment: Warnings are warnings and nothing more. "I was expecting the import to work without any warnings or issues." Why would you expect it not to have warnings? Developers of large projects often put in deprecation notes to start to alert users of the project and co-developers of impending changes that could possibly eventually break things. Does what you are trying to do after the import work still? If it doesn't make sense to you or interfere with that you are attempting to do then it's probably not pertinent to you at this time and you should continue to use the package as you planned. ...

Comment: Another way to phrase this is covered [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62415#issuecomment-1816685818) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62415#issuecomment-1884199361) where the TesorFlow developers were made aware of with [this filed issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62415). Feel free to read the rest of that thread for more insight. Otherwise consider it as a sign to 'Watch your step' and continue on.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: Upgrade to newer `tensorflow` version, e.g. TF2.x.
- Option 2: Manually change the code in `...\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py`. However, this might cause some other issues. For example, I got an error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python' has no attribute '__internal__'` when running OpenAI `Baselines`.

```py
import tensorflow.python as tf
# LABEL_DTYPES_FOR_LOSSES = {
#     tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy: "int32",
#     sparse_categorical_crossentropy: "int32",
# }
LABEL_DTYPES_FOR_LOSSES = {
    tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy: "int32",
    tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy: "int32",
}
```

- Option 3: Suppress [the warning function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/util/module_wrapper.py#L149-L151) in `D:\Users\*\miniconda3\envs\drlnd_py311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\module_wrapper.py`. Here `D:\Users\*\miniconda3\envs\drlnd_py311` is my `Miniconda` virtual environment, your path would be different. For some reason I have to use the older version `tensorflow`, and this one works just fine for me.

```py
  def _tfmw_add_deprecation_warning(self, name, attr):
    return False ##---✅ i added this line to bypass the whole function.
    """Print deprecation warning for attr with given name if necessary."""
    if (self._tfmw_warning_count < _PER_MODULE_WARNING_LIMIT and
        name not in self._tfmw_deprecated_checked):

      self._tfmw_deprecated_checked.add(name)

      if self._tfmw_module_name:
        full_name = 'tf.%s.%s' % (self._tfmw_module_name, name)
      else:
        full_name = 'tf.%s' % name
      rename = get_rename_v2(full_name)
      if rename and not has_deprecation_decorator(attr):
        call_location = _call_location()
        # skip locations in Python source
        if not call_location.startswith('<'):
          logging.warning(
              'From %s: The name %s is deprecated. Please use %s instead.\n',
              _call_location(), full_name, rename)
          self._tfmw_warning_count += 1
          return True
    return False
```

Ref: [GitHub issue #62415](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62415#issuecomment-1979627285)